# Get access to program's own directory

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0

this is a very simple issue.

**Note:** I am sure people have found and posted this same issue somewhere but I can't figure out the correct search terms to find it.

Okay, so here is my issue.
Let's say my program is stored at `C:\Program Files (x86)\MyProgram\Program.exe`.
Now in the program, it basically does

```
Directory.CreateDirectory(Application.StartUpPath + "\\Files")
```

So basically, this would create a directory called Files in the same folder as the program itself.
Assume that I *have* to create the folder in that location, so using a different location is not an option.

So the real problem is, **if its located in the c:\Program Files directory, my program gets "access denied" when I try to create the folder.**

So how can I get something like this to work without forcing the user to run it as an admin?

Comment: For such things, you could use commonuserpath or isolatedstorage.

Comment: Well since you are attempting to write in the Program Files directory, you need to either run your app as administrator or save it in a different location.  Program Files is a protected folder and only administrators may write to it.

Comment: "using a different location is not an option". Why? Please explain why you have come to this very **very** dangerous decision.

Comment: Well actually it would work, I'm just asking this question to figure out what to do if you can't.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If it's in Windows 7, if UAC is elevate, you won't be able to modify anything in c:\Program Files without rooting yourself via 'run as administrator'.

And since windows is a multi-user operating system, storing anything user-specific there is a recipe for disaster.

The right place for your program to put its data is in the appropriate special folder, which you can get/create via either

```
// user-specific application data is stored here
string userSpecificAppDataDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(
                                        SpecialFolder.ApplicationData ,
                                        SpecialFolderOption.Create
                                        ) ;

// application data common to all users is stored here
string commonAppDataDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(
                                  SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData ,
                                  SpecialFolderOption.Create
                                  ) ;
```

or one of the other `Environment.GetFolderPath()` overloads.

Comment: Well I guess this is the only method. Although I thought I have seen other programs read/write to their directory like Paint.NET's plugin/effects folder and stuff.

Comment: Is there any way to pull up the UAC box and ask for permission to do it? For example java update checker launches one, and some other things.

Answer (score 4):

In modern operating system the folder C:\program files (x86) is write protected by the OS. You can't create sub folders here without using an administrative account (and also in that case you will be asked to confirm this action unless you disable UAC). So the correct way to follow is to create your data folder in another place. The best option is the [CommonApplicationData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx) folder extracted using:

```
 Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData)
```

or the SpecialFolder.ApplicationData enum if your data should be differentiated by the current user of the application, or the SpecialFolder.MyDocuments if these files are produced by your user and need to be opened freely by other programs (or need to be included in a backup)

After you get the special folder provided by the OS to store application data remember to create a subfolder for your application and the other subfolders as required by your requirements

```
// In Win7 this usually resolves to C:\ProgramData, but do not use this folder 
string appCommon = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData);

// This resolves to C:\programdata\your_app_name\files
string appData = Path.Combine(appCommon, "your_app_name", "files");

// This will create all directories in the specified path one by one....
if(!Directory.Exists(appData)) Directory.CreateDirectory(appData);
```

Comment: +1 Lack of permissions for user accounts to write to "Program Files" folder is there for long time. Calling Windows 2000/XP "modern" is somewhat stretch :)

Answer (score 1):

You could try creating any files or folders you need during your installation procedure. I am not sure what success you would find if using a third party install creator, but my understanding is that items added via the <kbd>Application Files...</kbd> button in the <kbd>Publish</kbd> tab of the <kbd>Project Properties</kbd> section in Visual Studio then have access privileges kind of inherently granted for use by the application.

Comment: Good point, but or you make this an answer or you put this as comment

Comment: Sorry.. I am new to this, as a contributor at least. I can't see where to comment on the question, but I will RTFM and avoid repeating the mistake.

Comment: No problem. Look under the question and you will see a link 'add comment'.

Comment: Hmm.. I do not see that option, only 'share', 'edit' and 'flag'. Could it be because of my new status? I see nothing in the help about it either. Also, was my response downgraded because it was unhelpful, or badly submitted?? :/

Comment: Sorry, right, you can't post comments for now. See here http://stackoverflow.com/privileges For the downvote (Not mine) I can say that this is probably for the same reason I have posted my comment. But do not worry, a few days around here and you will be over  this little problem

Comment: @Steve - Alfie can't comment yet :)... Alfie - just make it into statement and it would be perfectly valid answer.

Comment: Answer revised, for what it's worth ;) Thanks for the feedback.